# if else if condition not working perfectly please tell me is there anything error in the following code

Tags: php

In this code when i enter wrong password in the login panel it shows me the error "Your Account is deactivated by admin. Please contact Admin" but it should show the "Your Mobile or Password is invalid. Login Again!" is there any mistake in the if condition please anyone help me regarding this.

```
<?php
       include("../includes/db.php");
       session_start();

       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          // username and password sent from form 

          $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mobile_l']);
          $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']); 

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM agent_profile WHERE mobile = '$mobile' and password = '$mypassword'";

          $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

          $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          $status = $row['status'];

          // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

          if($count == 1 && $status==1) {

             $_SESSION['login_user'] = $mobile;

             header("location: donor_list.php");
          }

              elseif($status==0)
          {
              $error="Your Account is deactivated by admin. Please contact Admin";
          }



              else {
             $error = "Your Mobile or Password is invalid. Login Again!";


          }


       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you storing plaintext passwords in the database?!

Comment: yes i stroed password as a plain text in database

Comment: print the ```$status``` variable on the screen.. i think you have problem with the variable you are fetching from above query.

Comment: Change `elseif($status==0)` to `elseif($status==0 &&  $count==1)`

Comment: @sansan For the safety of your users and if you don't want to end up paying a huge fine for negligence, I highly recommend you stop storing passwords as plain text right away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You must have `$count=1` when the account is deactivated by the admin and if it doesn't find any record then it means that there is no record in the `db` and `$count` should be `0` and since you are forcefully assigning something to the `$status` so it might assign it `0` when there is no record. So to differentiate the second and third conditions change `elseif($status==0)` to `elseif($status==0 && $count==1)`

Comment: Thanks lot. yes i made mistake.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line

```
elseif($status==0)
```

Since you only use two = signs, it will be true even if status is null (no rows are found). You could fix this by first checking if the count is 1 or by using three equal signs to also check for type differences.
IMO the best solution would be to first check if there are any results and then do the further checks like this:

```
if ($count == 1){
    if ($status == 1){
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $mobile;
         header("location: donor_list.php");
    }else{
        $error="Your Account is deactivated by admin. Please contact Admin";
    }
}else{
    $error = "Your Mobile or Password is invalid. Login Again!";
}
```